# Python: malformed array literal when inserting a string

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to read from a file and insert the data to a postgresql table in python using the `psycopg2`.

Here's the function I wrote:

```
def insert(file, table, col, conn):
    sql = "INSERT INTO "+table+"("+col+") VALUES(%s)"
    cur = conn.cursor()
    with open(os.path.join(DEFAULTS_FOLDER, file)) as fp:
        line = fp.readline()
        while line:
            cur.execute(sql, (line.rstrip(),))
            line = fp.readline()
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
    return
```

For some reason I get an error:

```
cur.execute(sql, (line.rstrip(),)) psycopg2.DataError: malformed array literal: "hello" LINE 1: INSERT INTO greetings(gname) VALUES('hello')
```

I also tried to insert a plain string and I still get the same error.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you might want to read http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message means that the column `gname` of the table `greetings` is an array, not a plain text. If it is a text array, the query should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO greetings(gname) VALUES('{hello}')
```

You should change the relevant fragment of your code, e.g.:

```
cur.execute(sql, ("{{{}}}".format(line.rstrip()),))
```

Comment: Yes, it was because my column was of type `char[]`. Thanks!